# How do i set else case in Dialogflow intent for Google Actions

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am new in google action and I am trying to implement google action for my aquarium shop app

And I need to response for  delivery available location queries
so I added available city details in Training phrases but my problem is if anyone asked with any counter name it is responding delivery is available in $geo-country 
but I need to replay if $geo-countery is not India then sorry, we don't provide delivery in geo-country 
How to do this?
 [image]

Answer (score 3):

Making an else case through the UI in Dialogflow isn't the easiest way. The easiest way to show different result for certain types of values would be to use [fullfillments](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/tutorials/build-an-agent/create-fulfillment-using-webhook). With fullfillments you can handle the interaction of an intent through code. For small projects Dialogflow provides a [code editor](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-configure#create_a_webhook_with_the_inline_editor) in which you can put an if statement that would show a different response for this intent.

An example of how to setup an intent which works with parameter input using fullfillments can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-webhook-slot-filling)

Using the inline editor you can write logic that will check if user mentioned India as a parameter for your intent and then change the response to what you want.

Comment: I found sys:any very easy to used if you can used one entity for the values and sys:any for any other combination

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found to create and if/ else type of response in dialogflow is by using sys:any specially if you already have an entity defined.  Just create for example

Phrase:  Do you deliver in Canada and mark canada with an entity so all of the values in that entity will be matched as valid delivery countries.

then create another phrase: Do you deliver in India and mark india with the sys:any entity.  Indicating that any other value outside of your entity values will be a non valid parameter.

Then create two text responses.  One will say yes we deliver in $parameter-name and the other will say no we dont deliver to $parameter-name

$parameter-name = the name you want to use for your variables.

Hopes this help